# How to target="_blank" with Advanced AJAX Page Loader?

Tags: html, ajax, wordpress

I installed [Advanced AJAX Page Loader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/) WordPress plugin and I am not sure how it works. I only want to open a link in new tab. I tried the typical target="_blank" attribute but it is no use. And external links are't working also. (It seems the plugins tries to load external page in my site but it process error.) SO how to link to external page in a wp page/post that have Advanced AJAX Page Loader installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.. You must add the link in **HREF Ignore List**.
Go to Admin panel > Setting > Advanced AJAX Page Loader. Then go to bottom and add the link (or part for internal link) And save it.
[image]